# AutoSend a custom HTML email to the user who has submitted the form

Tags: php, forms, email, send

I have already my own PHP Form working.. If someone fills my FORM and they will submit it.
I will recieve a email with all the filled details. Like: Name, Firstname, Email, Tel etc.

But i want that if someone will submit the form, they will recieve automaticly a Custom Email.

**Example:** User will fill all the details in the form and press send.
Then he will receive a email from me like: Hai Ben, Thanks for submitting my form.. I will contact you a.s.a.p

Right now the form is only sending MY an email with al the details..
But i want that Ben will get a confirmation e-mail. So if Ben will fill in as email: info@ben.com then the confirmation email has to go there

Comment: Then, utilize the same thing you've used for sending yourself an e-mail to send another to Ben!!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out this page here ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ); it'll help get you started asking questions well. In this case, we don't really have enough to work with. It'd be useful for you to show some of the relevant code you're currently using to send emails (only relevant code, without personal data, private keys, your actual email, etc). Then we may be of more help :)

Comment: @Luke Thanks Luke, this is my code: http://justpaste.it/phpsendmymail

Answer (score -1):

Here  is the example code for sending email:

```
$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'your-email@email.com';
$subject = "Title here";

$messagebody = <<<EMAIL

Thanks for submitting my form..
I will contact you a.s.a.p

EMAIL;

$header = "From: $from";

$send = mail($to, $subject, $messagebody, $header);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

But how can i add this variable : . $_POST['email'].

In the $to ?

Answer (score -1):

Show us your code so that we can suggest you, how to modify it to get what are you trying to achieve. There will be many different ways to do things, and the best would depend on how rest of your codes are.

Just like you are calling `mail` function in your code to email yourself with the details, you can call the `mail` function to send him an email.

Also, you dont hardcode info@ben into the script. You can just collect his email from the `POST` variables.

Sample, assuming your form works on `POST` and the email is stored in `email` in the post variables.

`$send = mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $messagebody, $header);`

Now do the bit of tinkering you would need to get it working with your script.

Comment: thanks for helping me, this is my source code : http://justpaste.it/phpsendmymail

Comment: Just like you set up the mail function there to mail you, make the subject and content and mail it to the user.

Comment: Yes but i want to send a custom text to the user,i tried too duplicate and change the values , but no results for me

Comment: What do you mean by no results? What error do you get?

Comment: Mujhe hindi aachi tharah nahi malum. So english please! I help people, but coding for them is not the tight way to help.

Comment: Glad you could learn things as well! :) If I gave you the codes, you wouldnt have learned how to do it.